# How to submit an AJAX form with ENTER key, from textarea in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, jquery

i'm developing a Ruby On Rails 2.3.8 application and I would like to know how to submit a remote_form_for when users press the ENTER key within the textarea.
I'm already doing the html replace from the controller's action, once the form is submitted.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.new-reply-text').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: this.form.onsubmit(),
            data: this.form.serialize(),
            success: {},
            dataType: json
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the form code:

```
<% remote_form_for :post, PostComment.new, :url => save_outside_comment_path(post_id), :html => {:method => :put, :onsubmit => save_outside_comment_path(post_id)} do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :comment, :rows => 1, :id => "txtOutsideComment_#{post_id}", :class => "new-reply-text" %>
      <%#= f.submit 'Publish', :onClick => "javascript:return validateField(this, #{PostComment::OUTSIDE_COMMENT_MIN_LENGTH}, #{PostComment::OUTSIDE_COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH});" %>
<% end %>
```

Please help me!
Thank you for reading

Comment: Since you're using a one-row text_area and effectively disallowing newlines, wouldn't a text_field be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

In your code this is pointing to the textbox so it will not work. Try this

```
jQuery('.new-reply-text').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this).closest("form");  
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: frm.attr("action"),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: {},
            dataType: json
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't work, firefox throw me "$(form).getElementsByTagName is not a function" and IE: "Object doesn't support property or method 'serialize'".

Comment: There was a double quote missing in my answer. I have edited it now can you please try?